# Choosing static class definition

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 3 sections in web.config that define values for the same static class:

```
<def_1
...
...
/>
<def_2
...
...
/>
<def_3
...
...
/>
```

I would like to choose, on the fly, which config to use.

```
<configSections>
  <section name="MyClass_1" type="myapp.def_1" />
  <section name="MyClass_2" type="myapp.def_2" />
  <section name="MyClass_3" type="myapp.def_3" />
</configSections>
```

I would like to be able to use MyClass_1, _2, or _3 as necessary.   Each class has definitions for Prod, QA and Dev environments and I want to be able to easily switch between environments.  Hopefully this isn't too vague.   Can anyone think of an easy way to do this?  Currently we just edit the web.config to use whichever class we want but I'd prefer not to have to edit that.

Additionally, I want to add that this is the only approach I can take as we have numerous applications using this and only a minor modification would be acceptable to try to facilitate their wishes.  If it can't be done (which I think it cannot) then that's the answer I'll give them.

Comment: [We all have jobs to do. It may be homework, or for assigned work at our job. No matter what, it’s our responsibility to get it done. Even when it seems like our task is too hard or we don’t know where to start, it is always worth the effort to at least try.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: Thats an approach I would never take. If you parametrize 3 diferent environments in the same config file, besides being easy to mantain, how would you be sure which config is being live in that environment?

Comment: Check other solutions like SlowCheetah for a better approach of your problem.

Comment: @Liam I believe the question is valid 'cause it could serve as a "why not to do it" question.

Comment: @JonGlazer is this being replaced during development or before publishing?

Comment: @bradbury9, I agree but I am stuck with it (added an additional paragraph to explain).  The modifications to the web.config are being done at the time of publish but I've been asked if it is possible to change environments (using this methodology) on-the-fly.

Comment: Check my answer, the configuration is relplaced automatically at run or publish time. Try to sell it as being bulletproof. The change is minimal, just need to add extra `.config.environmentName` files to the project and adding the SlowCheetah NuGet package.

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned that they want to be able to do this on a session by session basis without effecting other users.  Ya, this gets to be more impossible as we go.

Comment: Per session? You mean Different users have different `<MyClass>` settings? If thats the case I would use the Session_OnStart event and load that info per session. BTW virtual classes or intenfaces would be needed.

Comment: @JonGlazer its not impossible. You have to make a switch 1,2,3 depending on this choose the right config. Its static so it doesn't matter. save per user 1,2,3 option > give them a option to switch = problem solved. You don't have to touch the config then.

Answer (score 2):

You should have just one config section, but could have 3 different environment specific files and configure the config file so transformations are applied in your `<MyClass></MyClass>` settings.

A decent `.config` transformation plugin is SlowCheetah, check it out at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms

And a sample transformation is this.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="myServiceReference">

            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I am very familiar with transformations and we do implement them.  But now the new question is whether we can switch environments.

Comment: @JonGlazer You dont have to really switch. That why my question if you do it before publish. You can make multiple publish profiles and per profile set a transform. So depending on what profile you publish will result in the right .config.(unles i misunderstood you).

Comment: If the solution is configured properly, you could. Just configure the solution as `DEV/TEST/PROD` or whatever you need instead `DEBUG/RELEASE`

Comment: We want the ability to switch environments post publish and on a session by session basis.

Comment: I think "on a session by session basis" would be a code related problem, not a configuration related one.

Comment: Agreed.   No good way to accomplish this using this methodology.  Thanks for trying.